# PHP apache2 не работает запись в файл

Tags: php, apache, apache2

```
<?php
echo "start<br>";
//file_put_contents('space.txt', 'testing string'); пробовал
$file = fopen("space.txt", "w+");
fwrite($file, "test");
fclose($file);
echo "writed";
?>
```

Лог Apache:

```
[Tue Feb 20 18:47:42.877146 2018] [:error] [pid 22310] [client127.0.0.1:36690] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3
[Tue Feb 20 18:49:37.444313 2018] [:error] [pid 22304] [client 127.0.0.1:36700] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
```

но файл по-прежнему пустой.

Почему?

Comment: Открывайте лог апача и читайте, что в нём за ошибка.

Comment: потому что прав на запись небось нет. открыли файл дак проверьте результат, коли не работает _зы: write-wrote-written_